# Ошибка при выполнении программы на Python 3.5: import 'cv2' ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Программа:

```
# USAGE
# python test_imagenet.py --image images/dog_beagle.png

# import the necessary packages
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
from imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from vgg16 import VGG16
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the original image via OpenCV so we can draw on it and display
# it to our screen later
orig = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# load the input image using the Keras helper utility while ensuring
# that the image is resized to 224x224 pxiels, the required input
# dimensions for the network -- then convert the PIL image to a
# NumPy array
print("[INFO] loading and preprocessing image...")
image = image_utils.load_img(args["image"], target_size=(224, 224))
image = image_utils.img_to_array(image)

# our image is now represented by a NumPy array of shape (3, 224, 224),
# but we need to expand the dimensions to be (1, 3, 224, 224) so we can
# pass it through the network -- we'll also preprocess the image by
# subtracting the mean RGB pixel intensity from the ImageNet dataset
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
image = preprocess_input(image)

# load the VGG16 network
print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")

# classify the image
print("[INFO] classifying image...")
preds = model.predict(image)
(inID, label) = decode_predictions(preds)[0]

# display the predictions to our screen
print("ImageNet ID: {}, Label: {}".format(inID, label))
cv2.putText(orig, "Label: {}".format(label), (10, 30),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Classification", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
import 'cv2' ImportError: DLL load failed
```

Подскажите, как её исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вам нужно установить [Распространяемый пакет Visual C++ для Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=48145). Так как нужный для импорта файл не содержится в стандартном пакете Python.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200025/cant-import-cv2-dll-load-failed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048431/import-cv2-dll-load-failed-python-in-windows-64bit